# sorting list of objects by 2 property of that objects using linq

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

```
class TeamInfo
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public int Average { get; set; } 
}

TeamId  : 5,22,11,52,59 
Points  : 3, 8, 8,12,16
Average : 8,-2,-4, 1, 5
```

I have a list of TeamInfo objects(`List<TeamInfo> teamInfoList`)
I want to sort this list as follows;

```
TeamId | Points | Average
  59   |  16    |   5
  52   |  12    |   1
  22   |   8    |  -2
  11   |   8    |  -4
  5    |   3    |  -8
```

I need to sort first by Points(descending) and then Average(descending) if points are the same.

I tried this;

```
List<int> sortTeams = teamInfoList
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.TeamId , x.Points, x.Average })
            .OrderByDescending(x=>new { x.Key.Points, x.Key.Average })
            .Select(i => i.Key.TeamId).ToList();
```

I guess i need to implement `IComparable` but i have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ThenBy:

```
List<int> sortTeams = teamInfoList
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Points)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.Average)
    .Select(i => i.TeamId)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: sorry but not working, besides there is a groupby before orderbydescending

Comment: I don't think you need a GroupBy, unless I'm missing something... I assumed teamInfoList was a `List<TeamInfo>` that you needed to sort and select TeamId.

Comment: maybe better a List<TeamInfo>?